# XyMTeX problem with for French

Tags: packages, french, chemistry, xymtex

I want to use XyMTeX to draw some chemical structrures, but because I am French, I need to add `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` in order to be able to use accents. My problem is that with this package, my structure look like this:

[image]

as suppose of, without the French package.

[image]

My codes are:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xymtex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\author{Mathieu Mongrain}
\title{Les figures chimiques}

\begin{document}

\sixheterovi[{f\fivefusev[d]{1==N;4==N}{1S==CH$_3$}{b}}e]
  {2==N;4==N}
  {1D==O;3D==O;4S==CH$_3$}

\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xymtex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\author{Mathieu Mongrain}
\title{Les figures chimiques}

\begin{document}

\sixheterovi[{f\fivefusev[d]{1==N;4==N}{1S==CH$_3$}{b}}e]
  {2==N;4==N}
  {1D==O;3D==O;4S==CH$_3$}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone has a solution to this problem, considering that I need to keep my French package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I do not fully investigate the problem and this is just a workaround.

Output of the first MWE contains semicolons, which I think are arguments' delimiter, not actual texts. Some property (maybe category code or something?) of `;` is the cause of this issue, I guess.

The following code inspired by [this](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2008-June/010537.html) mailing list seems to work well.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xymtexpdf}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\author{Mathieu Mongrain}
\title{Les figures chimiques}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \shorthandoff{;}
  \sixheterovi[{f\fivefusev[d]{1==N;4==N}{1S==CH$_3$}{b}}e]
    {2==N;4==N}
    {1D==O;3D==O;4S==CH$_3$}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of my code]

---

As an aside, XyMTeX offers three drawing modes listed in “Three Modes of XyMTeX for Drawing Structural Formula” of [the package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xymtex/doc/XyMTeX-manual.pdf):

> - the `xymtex` package (`\usepackage{xymtex}` for the TeX/LaTeX-compatible mode),
> - the `xymtexps` package (`\usepackage{xymtexps}` for the PostScript-compatible mode), or
> - the `xymtexpdf` package (`\usepackage{xymtexpdf}` for the PDF-compatible mode),

The fact that `xymtex` is compatible with LaTeX's standard feature means that it is subject to the restrictions of `picture` environment. Assuming that you are using pdfLaTeX, it is recommendable to use `xymtexpdf`, which utilizes Ti*k*Z/PGF.

All of the three modes load the `xcolor` package and the `tikz` package loads the `graphicx` package, so you don't have to explicitly load `xcolor` and `graphicx` when you use PDF-compatible XyMTeX.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the semicolon is used by XyMTeX as a delimiter, but `babel-french` makes it into an active character, so defeating the search for it when the arguments to `\sixheterovi` and the other XyMTeX macros are parsed.

Workaround: enclose each diagram (or group thereof) into a `xym` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{xymtexpdf}% or xymtexps
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{xym}{%
  \shorthandoff{;:?!}\scantokens\expandafter{\BODY\empty}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{xym}
\sixheterovi[{f\fivefusev[d]{1==N;4==N}{1S==CH$_3$}{b}}e]
  {2==N;4==N}
  {1D==O;3D==O;4S==CH$_3$}
\end{xym}

\end{document}
```

The code emits a warning, but it does so also if `babel` is not loaded, so it shouldn't depend on the semicolon issue.